# R version 3.2.2_Windows 7 Professional: Unable to install swirl

Tags: r, swirl

[image: Screenshot of error message while trying to install swirl in R Version 3.2.2]

The error message obtained while trying to install swirl on Windows OS (Windows 7 professional) in R version 3.2.2 :

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Amrita/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error in download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: ''
Warning: unable to access index for repository cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning: unable to access index for repository www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning message:
package ‘swirl’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

Comment: Can you install other packages? Do you have a Windows Firewall that is not allowing R connect to the internet?

Comment: No, I am not able to install other packages and no the Windows Firewall is not blocking R. The same error message pops up when I try to install another package like boot

Comment: Sounds like your R session can't connect to the internet. Windows firewall seems a likely culprit, but you say it's not that. I don't really have other ideas.

Comment: It's not a connection issue. I have tried this installation in RStudio as well and am getting the same error and warning messages.I have tried the following: 1. Based on the responses to another similar question on stackoverflow, I unchecked the "Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP" option," in  Tools_>Global Options_> Packages in RStudio.However, I am unable to resolve this issue. 2. I am unable to change the CRAN mirror from Global to "0- Cloud - Rstudio, automatic redirection to servers worldwide" which was a suggested action for this problem , however still no luck.

Comment: This all sounds like *very* relevant information that should be edited into your question, not buried in a comment. Editing your question will bump it's activity and maybe it will get some more attention.

Comment: And I would also recommend changing your question title to "Unable to install any packages".

Comment: Thanks! I will take your advice and do the same. I am new to this and hence the error.

Comment: Also, you have said it's not a windows firewall issue, but it really does seem like R can't connect to the internet. If you have reasons to think it's not a firewall or internet settings issue (like, if you can successfully run `read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data", header = F)`), then I suggest you put that supporting information in the question as well. Even a screenshot of your control panel section for "Allow Programs to communicate through Windows Firewall", showing checkmarks for RStudio R Session would be reassuring.